# Calculate and return the value in the textfield, based on the input from the other textfield

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

So, what I am trying to do is to enter the values into the textfield 1 and textfield 2 and textfield 3 should automatically calculate and return the result. In my mainboard I have already added editingchanged and connected that @IBAction. The function works ONLY when I press "Backspace" button on the keyboard. My function for the TableViewController is below

class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
//identifier is saving 


@IBOutlet weak var Done: UIBarButtonItem!


var watts: Double = 0.0
var hours: Double = 0.0
var result: Double = 0.0
var hoursfromfunction: Double = 0.0
var wattsfromfunction: Double = 0.0
var receivedData = " "

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "saving", for: indexPath) as! SaveTableViewCell


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.WattsOutput.placeholder = "Enter Watts. Can be found on label"
        cell.WattsOutput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
        var textField100 = cell.WattsOutput
        textField100?.tag = 100
        textField100?.delegate = self
        //print ("Returned value is \(wattstext)")

        cell.HoursWeekOutput.placeholder = "Enter hours worked per week"
        cell.HoursWeekOutput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
        var textField200 = cell.HoursWeekOutput
        textField200?.delegate = self
        textField200?.tag = 200

        var textField300 = cell.ResultTextField
        resultFieldChanged(textField300!)

        return cell
        }

    return cell
    }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if (textField.tag == 100){
        //print ("Should return is called and the value is \(textField.text!) W ")
        watts = Double(textField.text!)!
        calculatewatts(watts)
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 200) {
        //print ("Should return is called and the value is \(textField.text!) hours")
        hours = Double(textField.text!)!
        calculatehours(hours)
    }

    //resultFieldChanged(textField)

    return true
}


func calculatehours (_ arg: Double) -> Double {
    print ("The function calculateHours returns \(arg)")
    return arg
 }

func calculatewatts (_ arg: Double) -> Double {
    print("The function calculateWatts returns \(arg)")
    return arg
}


@IBAction func resultFieldChanged (_ textField: UITextField) {
    hoursfromfunction = calculatehours(hours)
    wattsfromfunction = calculatewatts(watts)
    result = hoursfromfunction * wattsfromfunction
    print ("Output of functions are \(hoursfromfunction) & \(wattsfromfunction)")

    textField.text? = "\(result)"
    print ("Result is \(result)")
}
```

So, ResultTextField returns a calculated value ONLY when I tab the actual TextField and press the "Backspace Button"

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: what you want to do actually ?

Comment: Look at `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
      replacementString string: String) -> Bool` in UITextFieldDelegate: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield

Comment: @KKRocks enter values in textfield 1 and textfield 2 and textfield 3 will automatically output the multiplication result. I wrote it in the first sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTRL + Drag` your `textFields` to the your code and choose `Action`  as Connection

Set the event to `Editing Changed`

Now, In the IBAction block do what you want!

[image]

Comment: All of them? Or just the one that should automatically output the value?

Comment: All of theme should monitored

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Swift:**

```
yourTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then, implement the callback function:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

 if (textField.tag == 100){
    //print ("Should return is called and the value is \(textField.text!) W ")
    watts = Double(textField.text!)!
    calculatewatts(watts)
}
else if (textField.tag == 200) {
    //print ("Should return is called and the value is \(textField.text!) hours")
    hours = Double(textField.text!)!
    calculatehours(hours)
}


}
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Now it doesn't calculate at all.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. After I did what you advised, I keep having 0.0 in all of my textfields and I cannot overwrite them

Comment: did you add different all target for all three  textfields ?

Comment: Yes. and in mainstoryboard all three are delegates

Comment: I was able to figure out the calculation part but I still cannot write it textField300. So, the question is how do I access cell.ResultTextField from ActionButton?